# How to zoom charts in chart.js using angular 7

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular7

I have a `line-chart` and I want to zoom it but unable to do it. Here is my code

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart')

let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [7, 10, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: 'orange',
          borderColor: 'green',
          pointBorderColor: 'red',
          pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
        }]
      },
      options: {
        plugins: {
          pan: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'x',
            onPan: function () { console.log('I was panned!!!'); }
          },
          zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            drag: true,
            mode: 'x',
            onZoom: function () { console.log('I was zoomed!!!'); }
          },
        },
        responsive: true,
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
        <canvas id="myChart" style="max-width:95%;height:300px !important;"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used the following `plugin` for `zooming`

https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom#readme

I have also included `hammerjs` and `angular/animations` in my project.

**Update**

Why `pan` and `zoom` are unknown to typescript?

```
// package.json
"chart.js": "^2.7.3",
"chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^0.6.6",
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to Run `npm install chartjs-plugin-zoom` to install with npm
then do `import chartjs-plugin-zoom` in your .ts file and write plugin like this :

```
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x'
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x'
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 6):

The zoom options should be configured under the `options` not `options.plugins` setting.

```
  options: {
    pan: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'x',     
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,         
      mode: 'x',     
    },
    responsive: true
  }
```

See this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/3sx8zon2/2/

Comment: but in typescript, it's giving compilation error as there are no `pan` or `zoom` properties

Comment: and where you have imported the `zoom-plugin`?

Comment: It's in the sources of the fiddle. See if you have referenced the library correctly. And in the code shown by you are setting `pan` and `zoom` under plugins which is incorrect, it should be under `options`

Comment: is typescript giving wrong compilation error? because in options there are no `pan` or `zoom` options

Comment: I have tested and it is working. Why `pan` and `zoom` are unknown to `options` in typescript?

Comment: It has been updated since your answer. It will now work inside zoom attribute inside the plugins

Answer (score 5):

Install chart.js and chartjs-plugin-zoom

```
npm i chart.js -s
npm i chartjs-plugin-zoom -s
```

In Component.ts file import Chart and chartjs-plugin-zoom

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';
```

Logic to load chart

```
let myChart = new Chart('mapId', {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
},
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'xy'
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'xy'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
myChart.render();
```

In Component.html

```
<canvas id="mapId"></canvas>
```

Comment: this example works well with chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.7 and it is important to note that the 'plugins' ... section is put inside 'options' section. I missed this from the plugin documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I had used and work fine (Angular 12 - Chartjs 3.5.0):
1.

```
npm i chart.js -s
npm i chartjs-plugin-zoom -s
```

.2

```
import 'hammerjs';
import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';
Chart.register(zoomPlugin);
```

3. 

```
render: Chart;
this.render = new Chart(ctx, {type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: xxxxxxxx,
    datasets: [
    ......
  ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        zoom: {
          wheel: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          pinch: {
            enabled: true
          },
          mode: 'xy',
        },
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'xy',
        },
      }
    }
  },
```

}